# Javascript call a function several times with the arguments

Tags: javascript

This isn't totally necessary, I'm just trying to simplify my code. This is what I have:

```
   function fillWebsitePlaceFiller(number) {
     document.getElementById("placefillerWebsite" + number).innerHTML = placefillerWebsite;
   }

            fillWebsitePlaceFiller(1);
            fillWebsitePlaceFiller(2);
            fillWebsitePlaceFiller(3);
            fillWebsitePlaceFiller(4);
            fillWebsitePlaceFiller(5);
            fillWebsitePlaceFiller(6);
            fillWebsitePlaceFiller(7);
```

Is there a way I can call the function just once, and it will run through it 7 times with each argument?

Comment: it must be friday, all the crazy loop solutions are flooding in.

Comment: Haha :) @JimRubenstein

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Method 1 - iteration

```
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) fillWebsitePlaceFilter(i);
```

Method 2 - recursion

```
(function repeat(number) {
    fillWebsitePlaceFiller(number);
    if (number > 1) repeat(number - 1);
})(7);
```

Method 3 - functor application

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].forEach(fillWebsitePlaceFiller);
```

Method 4 - internal iteration

```
function fillWebsitePlaceFiller(times) {
    for (var number = 1; number <= times; number++) {
        document.getElementById("placefillerWebsite" + number).innerHTML = placefillerWebsite;
    }
}
```

Method 5 - extend function behaviour

```
Function.prototype.sequence = function(from, to) {
    for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) this.call(null, i);
};

fillWebsitePlaceFiller.sequence(1, 7);
```

Method 6 - XPath (warning: not tested)

```
var query = '//*[@id[starts-with(., "placefillerWebsite"]]';
var result = document.evaluate(query, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
while (var node = result.iterateNext()) node.innerHTML = placefillerWebsite;
```

Method 7 - jQuery

```
$('[id^="placefillerWebsite"]').html(placefillerWebsite)
```

I recommend one of the methods where you don't assume there are always seven of them.

Answer (score 21):

With ES6 it can be solved a bit more elegantly:

```
[...Array(7)].forEach((_, i) => fillWebsitePlaceFiller(i + 1))
```

Comment: Thats really great! Thanks for this, you save my day! ;)

Answer (score 5):

A simple for loop!

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    fillWebsitePlaceFiller(i);
}
```

Or, just as easily, modify fillWebsitePlaceFiller to do its own for loop:

```
function fillWebsitePlaceFiller() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
        document.getElementById("placefillerWebsite" + i).innerHTML = placefillerWebsite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
   function fillWebsitePlaceFiller(number) {
         for(i =0; i < number; i++)
         document.getElementById("placefillerWebsite" + i).innerHTML = placefillerWebsite;
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

use a loop

```
function doTimes(number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        fillWebsitePlaceFiller(i); 
    }
}

doTimes(7);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Best and easiest method to iterate one function multiple times is to use qalllib**

Pros - 1. Iterate sync/async as per requirement
       2. No promise violation
       3. Returns all results in single array like 
          Promise.all

Example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qalllib

```
npm i qalllib
const qall = require('qalllib')

function doSomething(params)
    {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject){
        //operations
    })
    }

qall.qAsyncAll(doSomething, [arg1, 
 arg2,arg3],3)
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response)
 }) //catchBlock
```

**Explanation:-**

```
qall.qAsyncAll(functionName without brackets,     
arrayOfArguments, arrayOfArguments.length)
```

**Other Example**

**Example**

```
let _ = require('underscore')

let response = ['some data','other data'] 

return Promise.all(_.map(response, function (data) { return 
functionName(data) }))
.then((response)=>{
console.log(response)
})
```

**Result**

```
['response1','response2']
```