# What is the JavaScript equivalent to Ruby's Enumerable#cycle?

Tags: javascript, ruby, loops, iterator

In Ruby, there's a method called, [Enumerable#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle), which allows for repeated loops by x number of times in a collection. I'm looking for something similar in JavaScript but could not find an equivalent.

Does anyone know of a JavaScript equivalent to Ruby's, Enumerable#cycle?

Context: I am trying to loop over the same array in JavaScript -- twice. Once iteration reaches the end, I would like the iteration to start from the beginning of the array and eventually stop. The stopping part is not hard -- it's the cycling of the iteration that I'm trying to achieve in JavaScript. I've been able to do this in Ruby, however, with said method.

Comment: It's not too hard to implement yourself. Ruby has great rich stdlib, so I wouldn't expect equivalents of each method to exist in JS-land. Even lodash and underscore don't seem to have it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing inbuilt which is equivalent to this but if you need to you can follow this post for more detail:

[Javascript call a function several times with the arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624307/javascript-call-a-function-several-times-with-the-arguments).

Apart from the options provided there, you could also extend the `Array.prototype` to enable this method:

```
Array.prototype.cycle = function (n, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        this.forEach(callback);
    }
}
```

and, could use this like following:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.cycle(2, function (i) { console.log(i); });
// this will print all the values two times
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no JavaScript built in (or even proposed to my knowledge) that can do this. However, it's not too hard to accomplish yourself.

Let's assume for a minute that your talking about Arrays, and let's waive away discussion about modifying prototypes or not. The simple version of what you want could be:

```
Array.prototype.cycle = function(cycleCount, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i < cycleCount; i++) {
    this = this.map(callback);
  }
}
```

Let's assume you have an array of numbers. Then you could call this by doing:

```
myNumberArray.cycle(2, function(num, i) {
  return num * 2;
});
```

We could even get fancy, and let you specify a different action for each cycle:

```
Array.prototype.cycle = function(cycleCount, callback) {
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call( callback ) === '[object Array]') {
    if(callback.length === cycleCount) {
      for(var i = 0; i < cycleCount; i++) {
        this = this.map(callback[i]);
      }
    } else {
      // Uhoh, we don't have the right number of callbacks
      throw new Error('If using multiple callbacks, the umber of callback\'s must match the number of cycles');
    }
  } else {
    for(var i = 0; i < cycleCount; i++) {
      this = this.map(callback);
    }
  }
}
```

There is more error checking you would need to do to make that robust, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: It's useful (imo) to add a check before adding methods to a prototype: `if (!('cycle' in Array.prototype) {...`